# WPF Sorting sub collection

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a collection of items that I would like to display in an ItemsControl. Each of these items will then have a collection of sub items that should be displayed horizontally inside each item. My question is how do I sort the sub items in XAML? I would normally use a CollectionViewSource but can't get that working in this case. Here's a simple example below. In this case somedata is my collection of items (string) and the items are collections of chars. I would just like to modify this example so that each row has all the chars sorted.

Put this is the constructor of a window:

```
        string[] somedata = new string[] { "afkhsdfgjh", "fsdkgjhsdfjh", "sdfjhdfsjh" };
        mainList.ItemsSource = somedata;
```

And this as the XAML (inside the Window tags)

```
<ItemsControl Name="mainList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CollectionViewSource for sub items as well.
Here's sample view model:

```
public class Item : ViewModel
{
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private String name;

    public ObservableCollection<String> SubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return subItems ?? (subItems = new ObservableCollection<String>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<String> subItems;
}
```

...and markup:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding SubItems}" x:Key="subItemsViewSource">
                        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                            <scm:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" />
                        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    </CollectionViewSource>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource subItemsViewSource}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In code behind initialize data context with some data:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
                Name = "John",
                SubItems = 
                {
                    "Mary", "Peter", "James"
                },
            },
            new Item
            {
                Name = "Homer",
                SubItems = 
                {
                    "Lisa", "Bart", "Marge"
                },
            }
        };
    }
```

The trick is to put resource which describes CollectionViewSource into layout control's resources of a master list item.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I found you can put the CollectionViewSource as a resource for ListBox/ItemsControl if you define the ItemsSource after the resource. It means using the long hand syntax for the ItemsSource but avoids having to define a potentially unnecessary parent object. Plus I think it wraps things up a bit neater as it's all defined on the ListBox.

Comment: BTW, should Marge really be a SubItem of Homer? :-))

Comment: @MikeKulls: ...if you look at their relationships more widely :D:D... About the question: yes, you're quite right. The main point is that resource must be defined **before** binding engine performs the binding. Of course, like many other cases in WPF, there's several ways to do that "before", and you free to choose favorite one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a value converter on the inner *ItemsControl*.  The converter would simply return the array, sorted.

```
public class ArraySortConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            return new string((value as string).OrderBy(ch => ch).ToArray());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

I suppose you would also have to add an *ItemsControl.ItemTemplate* to be able to actually use the converter, something like:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ArraySorter}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I should have mentioned I already have a converter like this that takes the data you are trying to sort and makes a decision on how to sort it based on the type. Eg, if you pass in an IEnumerable of staff then it knows to sort by LastName, FirstName. I was thinking there would be a pure XAML implementation. I guess if we took your converter and made it so it took a collection of SortDescriptions then it would be pretty much the same thing as a collectionViewSource. BTW, the second part of your answer is not necessary, the converter could be added to the existing binding